# Save Object having context with Gson

Tags: java, android, gson, android-context

I'm blocked between Context and Gson. I have a Product class I saved in a list using the GSON module. All is working. 
Now, I want to put all strings (of the Product class) in the string resources file. I tried with contextWrapper as bellow but doesn't work. I also tried by passing the context as an argument, but doesn't work too. 
How can I fix it ?

The Product Class :

```
public class Product extends ContextWrapper{
    private String mNumber;
    private String mDate;
    ...

    public Product(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    public void display(String data){
        String message = getString(R.string.message);    // access resources file
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, in an activity, I add the product into a list and save it. But there is an issue this line :

> new Gson().toJson(productList);

```
public my_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        ...
        List<Produit> listeProduit = new ArrayList<>();
        Product product = new Product(my_activity.this);
        ...

        productList.add(0, product); 
        String jsonProduct = new Gson().toJson(productList);
        listeEditor.putString(PRODUCT_LIST, jsonProduct);
        listeEditor.apply();
    }
    ...
}
```

Thank's for your help :-)

EDIT : SOLUTION

A simple solution is to pass the context as an argument of the function.

The Product Class :

```
public class Product{
    private String mNumber;
    private String mDate;
    ...

    public void display(Context context, String data){
        String message = context.getString(R.string.message);    // access resources file
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, just add the context when I ask the function :

```
public my_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        ...
        String data = "This is data";
        List<Produit> listeProduit = new ArrayList<>();
        Product product = new Product();
        display(this,data);
        ...

        productList.add(0, product); 
        String jsonProduct = new Gson().toJson(productList);
        listeEditor.putString(PRODUCT_LIST, jsonProduct);
        listeEditor.apply();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You have a error on the design of the model, if the model are not a Context it should not extend it, second, a model should not know android components, are you sure you need the method inside the object?

Comment: Tryed making it static? since it doesn't looks like to be using the inner fields of the object.

Comment: Thank Marcos for your answer. You're right. I ask the method outside the object. So I can give the context from the activity as an argument !